# group_concat vs another query

Tags: sql, join, group-concat

I would like to ask what would be better solution for my application. I have 1 table: marks - where I store marks - name, symbol and description. Then I have another table: products - each product has some marks 1 - N. Now I store marks of products in table products - column prod_marks - comma separated. Then I am getting those marks with another query. I get all the IDs of marks from products table and then I run query to get them. Is it good or would 1 query with join and group_concat to another table lets say: prodmarks (pmark_id, pmark_prodID, pmark_markID) be better?

Thanks

Edit:

table ci_products

[image]

table ci_marks (all possible marks with symbol and description)
[image]

Now my query looks like this:

```
SELECT `prod_id`, `prod_name`, `prod_desc`, `prod_num`, `prod_marks`, `prod_minprice`, `prod_minbid`, `prod_cat`, GROUP_CONCAT(img_url) images
FROM (`ci_products`)
JOIN `ci_prodimages` ON `ci_prodimages`.`img_pid`=`ci_products`.`prod_id`
WHERE `prod_cat` =  '4'
OR `prod_cat` =  '8'
OR `prod_cat` =  '9'
OR `prod_cat` =  '10'
GROUP BY `prod_id`
```

result of query:
[image]

Then I get in prod_marks something like this: 2,5,6
And then with those IDs I run another query to get the marks' name and description.

The 2nd idea was to make another join to new table: ci_prodmarks - there would me pmark_id, pmark_pid (fk to prod_id), pmark_mid (fk to mark_id) and also another group_concat on mark symbol and mark description

**Edit:**

This is what I get now. With these data I run another query to fetch those marks. The question is: should I make another table realated to ci_products and ci_marks to make M-N relation ? Also then I want to have query to fetch all products with marks related to them. When I use JOIN it would result multiple products for each image and mark so I used group_concat. So then I would use another group_concat for mark_mark and mark_desc ?

**Edit:**

New SQL with relation table with multiple result problem

```
    SELECT  `prod_id` ,  `prod_name` ,  `prod_desc` ,  `prod_num` ,  `prod_marks` ,  `prod_minprice` ,  `prod_minbid` ,  `prod_cat` , GROUP_CONCAT( img_url ) images, GROUP_CONCAT( mark_mark ) marks, GROUP_CONCAT( mark_desc
SEPARATOR  ";" ) mark_descriptions
FROM (
`ci_products` ,  `ci_marks`
)
JOIN  `ci_prodimages` ON  `ci_prodimages`.`img_pid` =  `ci_products`.`prod_id` 
JOIN  `ci_prodmarks` ON  `ci_prodmarks`.`pmark_pid` =  `ci_products`.`prod_id` 
AND ci_prodmarks.pmark_mid = ci_marks.mark_id
WHERE  `prod_cat` =  '4'
OR  `prod_cat` =  '8'
OR  `prod_cat` =  '9'
OR  `prod_cat` =  '10'
GROUP BY  `prod_id` ,  `mark_id`
```

Comment: Don't use comma-separated values in tables. Use a many-to-many relation table.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking. Can you show a small example of the data and the query you're asking about?

Comment: Still don't understand. Where in your query are the tables you mentioned in the question? Please post the data, the result you're trying to get, and the query you're using. Perhaps also make a sqlfiddle to demonstrate it.

Comment: Another edit. Hope now you can get it

Comment: Don't show us what you get now, show us what you WANT to get, and the query you've used to try to get it.

Comment: Well, I have managed to get what I want. Almost. Now my only problem is that when the product has more then 1 mark it is shown in result more than once. My query in edit.

Comment: Try `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT mark_mark)`

Comment: Didnt workedI also tryied to put it to mark_desc but still I get it there multiply

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle with sample data?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae173/1 here it is Also those marks should be in 1 row *,*** Dont know why it is like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your problems is that you are grouping by `mark_id`, which will mean you end up with multiple rows per product, and not all marks in each row, however this is only hiding another problem. Because you have multiple one to many relationships you are getting cartesian products in your join. Imagine the following simple example for prod_id = 1

**Images**

```
pid     url
--------------
1       some_url
1       some_other_url
```

**Marks**

```
pid     mark
-------------------
1       1
1       2
```

When you join these two on product ID you end up with

```
pid     url             mark
------------------------------
1       some_url        1
1       some_url        2
1       some_other_url  1
1       some_other_url  2
```

So you get all combinations of the two, so when you do GROUP_CONCAT on these you will get duplicates.

You either need to use subqueries to do your group concats:

```
SELECT  p.prod_id,  
        p.prod_name,  
        p.prod_desc,  
        p.prod_num,  
        p.prod_marks,  
        p.prod_minprice, 
        p.prod_minbid, 
        p.prod_cat, 
        img.images, 
        m.marks,
        m.mark_descriptions
FROM    ci_products p
        INNER JOIN 
        (   SELECT  i.img_pid, GROUP_CONCAT( i.img_url ) images
            FROM    ci_prodimages i
            GROUP BY i.img_pid
        ) img
            ON img.img_pid = p.prod_id 
        INNER JOIN 
        (   SELECT  ci_prodmarks.pmark_pid, 
                    GROUP_CONCAT( ci_marks.mark_mark ) marks, 
                    GROUP_CONCAT( ci_marks.mark_desc SEPARATOR  ";" ) mark_descriptions
            FROM    ci_prodmarks 
                    INNER JOIN ci_marks
                        ON ci_prodmarks.pmark_mid = ci_marks.mark_id
            GROUP BY ci_prodmarks.pmark_pid
        ) m
            ON m.pmark_pid = p.prod_id 
WHERE   p.prod_cat IN ('4', '8', '9', '10')
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae173/4)**

Or use DISTINCT in your GROUP_CONCAT:

```
SELECT  p.prod_id,  
        p.prod_name,  
        p.prod_desc,  
        p.prod_num,  
        p.prod_marks,  
        p.prod_minprice, 
        p.prod_minbid, 
        p.prod_cat, 
        GROUP_CONCAT( i.img_url ) images, 
        GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT m.mark_mark ) marks, 
        GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT m.mark_desc SEPARATOR  ";" ) mark_descriptions
FROM    ci_products p
        INNER JOIN ci_prodimages i
            ON i.img_pid = p.prod_id 
        INNER JOIN ci_prodmarks pm
            ON pm.pmark_pid = p.prod_id 
        INNER JOIN ci_marks m
            ON pm.pmark_mid = m.mark_id
WHERE   p.prod_cat IN ('4', '8', '9', '10')
GROUP BY p.prod_id, p.prod_name, p.prod_desc, p.prod_num, p.prod_marks, p.prod_minprice, p.prod_minbid, p.prod_cat
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae173/2)**

N.B.

I've also replaced this:

```
WHERE `prod_cat` =  '4'
OR `prod_cat` =  '8'
OR `prod_cat` =  '9'
OR `prod_cat` =  '10'
```

with a single `IN` statement:

```
WHERE   p.prod_cat IN ('4', '8', '9', '10')
```

Comment: Thanks working perfectly. Took some time to fit this into my php but working :)